# what is the best Collection to store and retrieve the duplicate key , value pairs?

Tags: java, collections

Which data structure should i use to store and retrieve the following data?
(key1,val1)(key1,val2)(key1,val3)(key2,val4)(key2,val5)(key2,val6)(key3,val7)(key3,val8)(key3,val9)

Please help me.

Comment: Are all values distinct?

Comment: Yes. All the values are distinct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Google Guava's [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and its subtypes [ListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) and [SetMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html).

From Multimap's javadoc: *A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a 
single key.*

Answer (score 2):

`Map<Key, Collection<Value>>` is the best approach

Comment: That is an interface, though, and not a data structure (i.e. an implementation).

Comment: @Thilo Yes its just a structure, any implementation of this structure should solve the issue.

Comment: The map interface does not define a data structure. A TreeMap, a HashMap, a Map backed by a key-value store, a Map backed by a relational database are all completely different data structures. And some of those may be better suited than others for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Map where values are collections like List/Set Depending on whether your pairs are distinct or not.

If you have distinct pairs you can go for something like Set interface:

```
   Map<key, Set<value>>

   Ex Map<key, HashSet<Value>>
```

If you do not have have distinct pairs((key1, val1), (key1, val1)) you can go for List interface:

```
Map<key, List<value>>    
Map<key, ArrayList <Value>>
```

Comment: Better use the interfaces in the declaration as well: `Map<key, Set<Value>>` or `Map<key, List <Value>>`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it would work for you, but you may consider reversing key/value if values are unique and use a standard `Map<ValueType, KeyType>`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `MultiValueMap` From `Commons collections`.

**Reference :**
 http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

**Sample :**

```
    MultiValueMap map = new MultiValueMap();
    map.put("SAN", 4);
    map.put("SAN", 6);
    map.put("TOM", 7);
```